# Netflix Feign Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix, netflix-feign

> Dependencies

`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
com.netflix.feign:feign-core:jar:8.16.2:compile
com.netflix.feign:feign-slf4j:jar:8.16.2:compile
com.netflix.feign:feign-jackson:jar:8.15.1:compile`

> Enabling Feign on SpringBootAppilication

`@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.vett.services.bucket.restclient")`

> Feign interface Client

`@FeignClient(name = "myClient", configuration = ClientConfigs.class, url = "https://my-endpoint");
public interface MyClient {`

> Results in this error

`org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException: Attribute 'value' in annotation [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient] must be declared as an @AliasFor [serviceId], not [name]`

> So far I have

As its unclear to me what the issue is i have used the `value` instead of `name`, my searching has not been successful i have see a few issues with feign annotation but not appear to be similar to this at all

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue, Once I added the below dependency , it started working :

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.SR7"}
}
```

I am using Spring boot 1.4 but Spring 4.3.6. Also Spring feign 1.2.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur when using multiple feign clients or bad package architecture. Sometimes this error occurs due to version incompatibilities, but in some projects we may not be able to change the versions. Therefore, you can solve the problem with the following codes. This codes worked for me.

Use this annotation in ApplicationStarter class:

```
@EnableFeignClients
```

Feign Client Interface:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;

@FeignClient(value = "account-service", url = "${feign.client.account-service}", path = "/account/api/v1")
public interface AccountServiceClient {
  @RequestLine("POST  /customer/{email}/?name={accountName}")
  Long registerCustomer(@Param("email") String email, @Param("accountName") String accountName);
}
```

Define bean for multiple feign usage:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("account-feign-client")
public AccountServiceClient accountServiceClient() {
    return Feign.builder().target( AccountServiceClient.class,"${feign.client.account-service}");
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("mail-feign-client")
public MailServiceClient mailServiceClient() {
    return Feign.builder().target( MailServiceClient.class,"${feign.client.mail-service}");
}
```

Autowire in service:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("account-feign-client")
private AccountServiceClient accountServiceClient;
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```